# How to get the text attribute of a input element? - webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
<ul class="list-group opened-list d-none" xpath="1">
    <li class="list-group-item col-12" xpath="1">My team</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-12" xpath="1">My name</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-12" xpath="1">My film</li>
    <li class="list-group-item col-12" xpath="1">My football teammate</li>
  </ul>
```

**Dropdown list without select tag**

Comment: I don't see an input element. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all **li** elements use `.list-group.opened-list .list-group-item` css selector. 
Code below wait visibility of **li** elements and then print text for each:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> options = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".list-group.opened-list .list-group-item")));
options.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.getText()));
```

If you want to select one of the element by text, check example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488870/how-to-select-a-dynamic-value-in-select2-dropdown-for-selenium/58489389#58489389).